# The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() exception in ews

Tags: c#, outlook, console-application, threadpool, exchangewebservices

Hello everyone i am stuck with this exception and it is stopping my service. please help following is the full stack trace.

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.Net.WebException at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest)

> Exception Info: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest ByRef)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection.Open()
> at ERSupportGetOutlookEmail.EmailExchange.OnDisconnect(System.Object, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SubscriptionErrorEventArgs)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection.InternalOnDisconnect(System.Exception)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.StreamingSubscriptionConnection.OnRequestDisconnect(System.Object, Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingRequestDisconnectEventArgs)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.InternalOnDisconnect(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingRequestDisconnectReason, System.Exception)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetStreamingEventsResponse.ReadElementsFromXml(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.LoadFromXml(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader, System.String)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetStreamingEventsRequest.ParseResponse(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader)
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.HangingServiceRequestBase.ParseResponses(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Here is my code please look into this

```
            public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Watch()
            {
                //Configuration options for a public client application (desktop/mobile app)
                var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"],
                    TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]
                };

                //Creates a PublicClientApplicationBuilder from a clientID.
                var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

                //access permission.
                var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };

                try
                {

                    // Make the interactive token request
                    var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(ewsScopes, EmailID, ConvertToSecureString(Password)).ExecuteAsync();
                    //var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

                    // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
                    ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
                    ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                    ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
                   
                    Console.WriteLine("New Email details will display below:-");
                    // Make an EWS call                                
                    CreateStreamingSubscription(); //Creating subscription.               
                }
                catch (MsalException ex)
                {
                    Email.onErrorOccur(ex.Message, "EmailExchange Watch event MsalException", ex.StackTrace);                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Email.onErrorOccur(ex.Message, "EmailExchange Watch event", ex.StackTrace);                    
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the code you posted its whats in CreateStreamingSubscription that is causing the exception, its just being caught by the code block you posted which isn't doing any Exchange requests just authentication. Can you give more detail on when it happens eg does the code work for a while and this happens or it just doesn't work? if it just doesn't work may TLS 1.2 so i would suggest including in

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Comment: hello Glen Scales, it works well for some 12 hours after that it is throwing exception.

Comment: If its worked for 12 hours and then throw the exception i would say its nothing to do with the code or Exchange. You need better exception handling that will reconnect or recreate the subscription when and where necessary. This is just standard practice with streaming notification eg they need to maintain connectivity for 24 hours and any number of components from client firewalls, server firewall, mailbox being moved, server being reboot etc can cause an issue. You just need to write good recovery and reliability code to maintain the subscription.